# Iterating over a string in coffeescript without having to create an array

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have several places in my code where I need to iterate over a string and perform operations char by char. My node.js application needs to do this dozens of times per request and often the length of the strings can be fairly long.

The only way I've seen to convert a javascript like the one below into coffeescript is to create an array based on the length of the string. The problem with this I have is it's an extra thing to do on the hardware side, takes up extra memory, and just seems unnecessary (my node application processes dgrams - up to thousands a second - so all this extra work adds up).

**The JavaScript way:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { /* Do stuff with str here */ }
```

**The suggested CoffeeScript way**

```
for i in [0..str.length]
  # Do stuff here
```

Again, I think it's silly to force the creation of an array object when the traditional for loop doesn't have to mess with that step from a hardware perspective.

My only work around I've found is to use while loops like:

```
i = 0
while i < str.length
  # Do stuff
  i++
```

While that works, that's far more verbose than even the straight JavaScript way of just using a simple for loop.

Is there a way to use a for loop in CoffeeScript without having to generate superfluous arrays in order to perform basic iterations?

Comment: Why iterate over a string? What's wrong with the first way?

Comment: @Christoph why *not* iterate over a string? Maybe he's parsing it.

Comment: How do you mean _"without having to generate superfluous arrays"_?
You can just use a string as if it were a array: `console.log("Hello world"[7]);`

Comment: @Pointy is correct. In my case I'm performing bitwise operations converting buffers to and from strings/numbers. It's a tedious enough process to get bits to/from bytes and CoffeeScript is only adding another layer of complexity.

Comment: `.length` is a native string method and also iterating with `str[i]` is  okay, i don't see the problem.

Comment: @Dan are you under the impression that "[0..str.length]" is the creation of an array?

Comment: @Cerbrus - you're right but only if I create yet another array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,....] in order to be able to iterate over that string. Which is the point of my frustration. I want to be able to treat my string of data as the array it essentially is without having to generate yet another array in the process.

Comment: `str = 'test-string';for(var i = 0;i < str.length;i++){// work with str[i] is fine here}` works perfectly. What is your problem?

Comment: Why would you need to generate that array? Have you posted all relevant code in your question?

Comment: for i in [0..str.length] is a bad idea causing index out of bound :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't actually create an array if it doesn't have to. Look at the compiled JS. This CoffeeScript:

```
str = "hello"
for i in [0..(str.length-1)]
  alert(i)
```

Generates the following JavaScript:

```
var i, str, _i, _ref;

str = "hello";

for (i = _i = 0, _ref = str.length - 1; 0 <= _ref ? _i <= _ref : _i >= _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
  alert(i);
}
```

No array was actually created.

(Subtracting 1 to .length to avoid an undefined)

Comment: Beat me to it :D. @Dan for future reference, the "Try" page on the coffeescript site can be good for these one-off generation examples

Comment: Wow, I've never seen a `for` loop that large for something that simple o.O

Comment: @Cerbus coffeescript iteration with that syntax is bidirectional, and the compiler wouldn't know at this point if "0 to arg" is counting up or down. With the inclusion of "by 1" you can clue the compiler into a positive count generating something you're likely more used to. `for i in [0..str.length] by 1`

Comment: @vcsjones indeed you're right! My foot fits nicely in my mouth. Since expressions in coffeescript like `arr = [0..9]` creates an array I **ass**umed `for i in [0..str.length]` did the same thing. It does not - and my ignorance has now been officially archived on the interwebs :). Thanks for helping me see the obvious.

Comment: Isn't it `for i in [0..str.length-1]`?

Comment: @Puce Possibly, I just wrote my answer based on what the OP provided in their example. Perhaps OP intentionally wanted to be inclusive of the length. However, I would recommend using `for i in [0...str.length]` (notice the extra dot), that "excludes" the last number. [Example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%5B1...4%5D)

Comment: Wow, obscure as heck. Good to know but I'm sticking to `length-1`, easier to read imho

Answer (score 7):

You may also iterate over the string itself:

```
for ch, i in str
  # Do stuff here.
```

Comment: Nice. That from of the `for` loop only depends on `str` having a `length` property and handling `str[]`.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript (And thus, also CoffeeScript), `strings` can be accessed like you'd access `arrays`:

```
console.log("Hello world".length);       // returns "11"
console.log("Hello world"[6]);           // returns "o"
console.log("Hello world".indexOf("w")); // returns "6"
```

I don't see you initializing arrays in any of those loops.

You should be able to use plain JavaScript in your CoffeeScript files, though, if that solves the issue.